# How to read a request's body in an actix-web 1.0 middleware?

Tags: rust, middleware, actix-web

I want to read out the body in a middleware in actix-web 1.0. I'm using the closure-style middleware using `wrap_fn`.

My basic setup is this:

```rust
let mut server = HttpServer::new(move || {
    ActixApp::new()
        .wrap_fn(|req, srv| {
            srv.call(req).map(|res| {
                let req_ = res.request();
                let body = req_.magical_body_read_function();
                dbg!(body);
                res
            })
        })
});
```

I need that `magical_body_read_function()` which sadly doesn't exist.

I hacked together something that looks like it could work by reading the examples and using `take_payload()` but it didn't work, sadly:

```rust
let mut server = HttpServer::new(move || {
    ActixApp::new()
        .wrap_fn(|req, srv| {
            srv.call(req).map(|res| {
                let req_ = res.request();
                req_.take_payload()
                    .fold(BytesMut::new(), move |mut body, chunk| {
                        body.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
                        Ok::<_, PayloadError>(body)
                    })
                    .and_then(|bytes| {
                        info!("request body: {:?}", bytes);
                    });
                res
            })
        })
});
```

Gives me

```
error[E0599]: no method named `fold` found for type `actix_http::payload::Payload<()>` in the current scope    --> src/main.rs:209:26
    | 209 |                         .fold(BytesMut::new(), move |mut body, chunk| {
    |                          ^^^^
    |
    = note: the method `fold` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut actix_http::payload::Payload<()> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I then tried an approach using the full middleware:

```rust
pub struct Logging;

impl<S, B> Transform<S> for Logging
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = LoggingMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = FutureResult<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(LoggingMiddleware { service })
    }
}

pub struct LoggingMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
}

impl<S, B> Service for LoggingMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Box<dyn Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self) -> Poll<(), Self::Error> {
        self.service.poll_ready()
    }

    fn call(&mut self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        Box::new(self.service.call(req).and_then(|res| {
            let req_ = res.request();
            req_.take_payload()
                .fold(BytesMut::new(), move |mut body, chunk| {
                    body.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
                    Ok::<_, PayloadError>(body)
                })
                .and_then(|bytes| {
                    info!("request body: {:?}", bytes);
                });
            Ok(res)
        }))
    }
}
```

which sadly also resulted in the very similar looking error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `fold` found for type `actix_http::payload::Payload<()>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:204:18
    |
204 |                 .fold(BytesMut::new(), move |mut body, chunk| {
    |                  ^^^^
    |
    = note: the method `fold` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut actix_http::payload::Payload<()> : futures::stream::Stream`
            `&mut actix_http::payload::Payload<()> : std::iter::Iterator`
            `actix_http::payload::Payload<()> : futures::stream::Stream`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of the fine people in the actix-web Gitter channel, I came to this solution which I also made [a PR](https://github.com/actix/examples/pull/170) for.

Full solution is:

```rust
pub struct Logging;

impl<S: 'static, B> Transform<S> for Logging
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = LoggingMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = FutureResult<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(LoggingMiddleware {
            service: Rc::new(RefCell::new(service)),
        })
    }
}

pub struct LoggingMiddleware<S> {
    // This is special: We need this to avoid lifetime issues.
    service: Rc<RefCell<S>>,
}

impl<S, B> Service for LoggingMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>
        + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Box<dyn Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self) -> Poll<(), Self::Error> {
        self.service.poll_ready()
    }

    fn call(&mut self, mut req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let mut svc = self.service.clone();

        Box::new(
            req.take_payload()
                .fold(BytesMut::new(), move |mut body, chunk| {
                    body.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
                    Ok::<_, PayloadError>(body)
                })
                .map_err(|e| e.into())
                .and_then(move |bytes| {
                    println!("request body: {:?}", bytes);
                    svc.call(req).and_then(|res| Ok(res))
                }),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems like the body gets consumed by the middleware. Do you know if it is possible to only read the body in the middleware while letting it pass through to the service?

Comment: I believe this is not possible due to the way actix-web is designed. Basically, in order to read the body, you have to get it moved into you. You could try putting it back into the Request somehow.

Comment: You can rebuild the payload and add it to the ServiceRequest

Answer (score 5):

Building on svenstaro's solution you can do something like the following  to rebuild the request after cloning the stripped bytes.

```
    fn call(&mut self, mut req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let mut svc = self.service.clone();

        Box::new(
            req.take_payload()
                .fold(BytesMut::new(), move |mut body, chunk| {
                    body.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
                    Ok::<_, PayloadError>(body)
                })
                .map_err(|e| e.into())
                .and_then(move |bytes| {
                    println!("request body: {:?}", bytes);

                    let mut payload = actix_http::h1::Payload::empty();
                    payload.unread_data(bytes.into());
                    req.set_payload(payload.into());

                    svc.call(req).and_then(|res| Ok(res))
                }),
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Payload` implements `Stream<Item = Bytes, Error = _>`, so there is no reason you cannot use the same trick as for other frameworks:

```
req_
    .take_payload().concat2()
    .and_then(|bytes| {
         info!("request body: {:?}", bytes);
    });
```

That is, if you had a proper `Payload` from a POST/PUT request. Since you've used `wrap_fn()`, you've effectively set up a middleware. Those run across all requests, and do not allow you access to the `Payload` (partly because you can only take it once).

As such, you're out of luck, I think.

Comment: No dice, sadly:
error[E0599]: no method named `concat2` found for type `actix_http::payload::Payload<()>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:209:26
    |
209 |                         .concat2()
    |                          ^^^^^^^

Comment: The error doesn't even tell you about importing a trait below it?

Comment: Nope, I know those already and the compiler is helpful there. Sadly, I think the type that comes out of `take_payload()` is not, as I'd expect, `Payload<Stream>`.

Comment: @Svenstaro Yeah, I thought `wrap_fn` would do more, but all it does is create a middleware and since the lowest common denominator for payload in that is `()`, you're stuck with `Payload<()>`. You need to explicitly define your service :-(

Comment: _Payload implements Stream<Item = Bytes, Error = _>,_ `Payload<S>` implements `Stream` only if  `S` implements `Stream`, in the case for OP `S` is `()` ,  `()` is not an implementor of `Stream`, [please see](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#implementors)

Comment: Sadly, using the full middleware results in roughly the same error. Please check the updated answer. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Checking in, I have not forgotten about your question and may have a solution, but it's a lot more complex due to the requirements on middlewares :-(

Comment: I believe I've found a good fix. I'll post an answer for this and also create a new examples for the actix-examples repo so that other people may benefit.

Comment: Please do :-) I'm still struggling to see how you could do it without destructuring `ServiceRequest` and reforming it after